# color to B/W javascript affect

Tags: javascript, html, image, effect

Is there any known/simple/open-source library that provide
a javascript function that will switch colored picture that is displayed in an html page into a black and white

That can be used in all the most used browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome)?

I mean something like:

```
<html>
...
<img id="myPic" src="pic.jpg">
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function onEvent(){
  var pic = document.getElementById("myPic");
  magicFunctionToBlackAndWhite(pic);
}
</script>
</html>
```

looking for that **magicFunctionToBlackAndWhite()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one solution that works across all browsers, but you can combine different solutions:

For IE, use the following CSS: `filter: Gray`

A lot of other browsers supports `canvas`, so you should be able to [use this javascript code](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsCanvasGrayscale/index.html) for that.

Of course it should't be too much of a hassle to make an image b/w in a serverside language such as .net, so you could always have a javascript that in principle does something like the following:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].src = 'convertimage.aspx?img=' + imgs[i].src;
}
```

...and then have all of the magic happening on the server.

Comment: ok, looks like the example here(http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsCanvasGrayscale/index.html)
will do the job.

Although I thought there is something more elegant like when changing the transpernecy of an image we can use:
element.style.opacity

Answer (score 0):

That might be somehow possible by using the `<canvas>` element, but I would recommend you to do the black and white versions yourself, either manually or through some sort of script. Trust me – it'll save you a lot of trouble.